# Okay Google option to open from lock screen using Moto G 3rd Gen

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, ok-google, motorola-moto-g3

Can anyone help me? On my Moto g 3rd Gen I cannot open by saying OK Google from the lock screen. In fact it doesn't even give me that option. The only option that i have when i go to my OK Google detection in the settings is "FROM THE GOOGLE APP"-Say OK Google to start a voice search from the Google app or any Home screen in the Google Now Launcher. That's it. I have tried everything. I have spoken to Motorola a number of times and they are, to say the least, clueless. I also contacted Google and they understood what I was saying but had no idea's on how to fix it. If anyone can help me - Please, I'm taking suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's just the gapp you have. I had a rom that had gapps preinstalled and the option wasn't there, but when I flashed official gapps from opengapps.org it gave me the option.